# Google Maps API v2 for Android: Cannot draw like deprecated Overlay

Tags: android, overlay, google-maps-android-api-2

I have developing an Android application, and I have moved from Google Maps for Android API v1 to v2.

With deprecated version 1 I created an Overlay for drawing some colored shapes (delimiting zones) and info text over my map, but now I have been viewing API v2 and cannot do the same.

I have trying to use Polygon property, but it doesn't fill with any colour, maybe because my shapes cannot be drawing in counterclockwise due to the pattern of them, for example a shape with 'U' pattern. Also, I don't know either how to put a text (no marker, just text) over the map.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now my shapes are filled with colours, but still don't know how to put a text in the map. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> still don't know how to put a text in the map

Create a `Bitmap` containing your text, and use [a `GroundOverlay`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay), or possibly [a `TileOverlay`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileOverlay).

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, I solved this problem using Bitmap, as you said, and assigning it to an icon Marker... `markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))`