# Android maps - issues with getting keys

Tags: android, google-maps

About 6 (or more) months ago i have started creating an Android project (for old, 2.1 version) that uses Google maps. As i already developed some apps for Android (i do have a "Play" account and some other apps on the market) i managed to easily obtain debug map key, placed it inside of my map xml element. Everything works fine in the emulator.

Now, my app is done and i wanted to get "release" API key, but it looks like many things have changed in the meantime (no need to tell you how frustrating are those rapid changes Google is introducing) - i'm using old style "mapview", but documentation says that that approach isn't supported anymore?

My map activity is simple, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<g.maps.MyMapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="MY_DEBUG_KEY"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true" />
```

All i want is to replace the "DEBUG" key with "RELESE" key. I don't want to change my Android manifest, i don't want to use new "map fragments", i don't want to "drop support for 2.1 version".
How can i get and use RELEASE key with this new system of getting and placing keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i'm using old style "mapview", but documentation says that that approach isn't supported anymore?

You cannot obtain API keys for Maps V1 (old style "mapview") anymore. If you have keys, those keys will continue to work, at least until such time as they shut off Maps V1 entirely.

> How can i get and use RELEASE key with this new system of getting and placing keys?

You cannot obtain API keys for Maps V1 (old style "mapview") anymore. Your choices are:

- move to [Maps V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) (new "map fragments")
- switch to a third-party mapping engine like OpenStreetMap and OSMDroid (which may offer an API that is closer to what you are presently using)
- remove the maps from your app
- do not release the app

Note that the announcement related to the retirement of Maps V1 was made ~7 months ago, as [I was already warning developers about this on December 17](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/12/17/maps-v1-keys-going-going.html).

Comment: This is not happening! It can't be! Not only i'm using mapview, i'm also drawing everything on it using "draw()" method (that is removed from new maps)! Why, o why Google doesn't slow down it's development, or at least (like Java) keeps old methods for long time :(

Comment: @guest86: With regards to `draw()`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798419/freeform-drawing-with-android-maps-v2 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269042/google-maps-api-v2-for-android-cannot-draw-like-deprecated-overlay for some ideas.

Comment: Thank you. Google disappointed me big time... My app is ready for production after 6 months of development, web server is ready and now... I don't think other map solutions would help me as i'm using many features of Google maps like measuring distance, scaling drawn figures depending on zoom level etc...